# TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I find button using code:

```
cy.get('[class="ng-select ng-select-multiple ng-select-searchable ng-untouched ng-valid ng-select-focused ng-select-opened ng-select-top ng-dirty"]')
  .children('[class="ng-select-container ng-has-value"]')
  .children('[title="Clear all"]')
```

Then I do several actions - like click, check is visible etc. All that works if I have this code directly in the test file.

```
getClearObjectsButton() {
  cy.get('[class="ng-select ng-select-multiple ng-select-searchable ng-untouched ng-valid ng-select-focused ng-select-opened ng-select-top ng-dirty"]')
    .children('[class="ng-select-container ng-has-value"]')
    .children('[title="Clear all"]')  
}
```

However, if I use a secondary file with created functions I get an error as in the title.

```
register.getClearObjectsButton().click()
```

```
cypress_runner.js:174495 TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at Context.<anonymous> (tests?p=cypress\integration\create_user\check_objects_selector.js-106:580)
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly new to Cypress but I suggest you try following:

1) **The most likely issue/solution - Is that "secondary file" even executed?** I remember having some issues when calling my helper functions defined in `cypress/support/commands.js` file. Is commands.js the "secondary file" you mentioned? Seems you're calling it with `register.getClearObjectsButton()`. What is `register`? If you put `getClearObjectsButton` method into `cypress/support/commands.js` file, you can then call it in all your test files with `cy.getClearObjectsButton()`

2) If it is executed, try to execute click in that secondary file as well. Does it work?

3) Also, if you're sure your method is executed, I guess you've expected that yield of cypress `.get` function stays "active" but it probably isn't the case. Try to save it in a variable and return from your `getClearObjectsButton` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the file is executed.

```
    import CreateUser from "C:/cypress-s/cypress/classes/CreateUser.spec.js";

    describe('Check role selector', () => {
        const register = new CreateUser();

     it.only('clear field button', () => {
            register.fillObject(0)
            register.getClearObjectsButton().click()
     })
})
```

I use functions from this file for other tests and I never faced this issue.

Comment: Cypress recommended using commands to do this. Did you decide to go this way or is there anything I am missing from cypress?

Answer (score 0):

Another thought - maybe that will help you someway.

```
  getClearObjectButton() {
    cy.get('[class="ng-select ng-select-multiple ng-select-searchable ng-untouched ng-valid ng-select-focused ng-select-opened ng-select-top ng-dirty"]').children('[class="ng-select-container ng-has-value"]')
    .children('[title="Clear all"]').click()
  }

    it.only('clear field button', () => {
        register.fillObject(0)
        register.getClearObjectButton()
})
```

Works perfectly fine, but if I change click() location I get mentioned error.

```
  getClearObjectButton() {
    cy.get('[class="ng-select ng-select-multiple ng-select-searchable ng-untouched ng-valid ng-select-focused ng-select-opened ng-select-top ng-dirty"]').children('[class="ng-select-container ng-has-value"]')
    .children('[title="Clear all"]')
  }


   it.only('clear field button', () => {
        register.fillObject(0)
        register.getClearObjectButton().click()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Return is the key : )

```
  getClearObjectButton() {
   rreturn cy.get('[class="ng-select ng-select-multiple ng-select-searchable ng-untouched ng-valid ng-select-focused ng-select-opened ng-select-top ng-dirty"]').children('[class="ng-select-container ng-has-value"]')
    .children('[title="Clear all"]')
  }


   it.only('clear field button', () => {
        register.fillObject(0)
        register.getClearObjectButton().click()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error while calling the object from a class.

```
//Login
login.getUserName().type(this.testdata.userDocumentM)
login.getPassword().type(this.testdata.passwordDocumentM)
//cy.get('#form-login > .form-group.text-center > .btn').click()
login.getLoginButton().click()
```

But while running at normal its oK.

```
 //Login
login.getUserName().type(this.testdata.userDocumentM)
login.getPassword().type(this.testdata.passwordDocumentM)
cy.get('#form-login > .form-group.text-center > .btn').click()
//login.getLoginButton().click()
```

I also tried with force

```
//login.getLoginButton().click({force:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the return key work while defining getClearObjectButton() class? like:

```
getClearObjectsButton() {
  return cy.get('[class="ng-select ng-select-multiple ng-select-searchable ng-untouched ng-valid ng-select-focused ng-select-opened ng-select-top ng-dirty"]')
    .children('[class="ng-select-container ng-has-value"]')
    .children('[title="Clear all"]')  
}
```